# Java Project Language Level changing on its own when I build a new project - IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

Whenever I build a new project the project language level is automatically changed on it's own down to 6. Which means that whenever I try to build the project I get errors and warnings etc. I have been trying to change the project defaults but this does not help. I have also attempted to set the byte code version as 9 by default.

This is my Project Structure before I set up a new project:

[image: This is my project structure before I build a new project]

After applying these settings I create a new hello world (console) application. I then run the project and get these errors:

[image]

The only code in the main class is `public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Hello, World");
}
}
```

`

I then go and check the project structure and see that the project language level has been changed. Why is it doing that and how do I stop this from happening? I have been researching this problem and even contacted the JetBrains forum but nothing helps. + I have also attempted to set the 'project byte version' as 9 by default but this also gets changed after I create a new project.

This is what project structure looks like after running the project:

[image]

During my research I found out that if this is a maven project you can fix this by changing the pom.xml file but this is just a java console application.

These are the java compiler settings:

[image]

FYI by default it is set to 9; when the project is created it is set to nothing.

Comment: Is it a maven project? If so, [update the `pom.xml` accordingly.](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)

Comment: It is not a maven project. It's just a simple Java console application

Comment: Could you please attach screenshot from "Settings | Build... | Compiler | Java Compiler"?

Comment: yeh I'll do that now @y.bedrov

Answer (score 0):

Try change the same settings using `File -> Other Settings-> Default Settings`

Comment: The default settings are all correct (they are all set to be 9 by default). However if you look at the project structure the language level is 6. Which creates errors.

Comment: try to change your JAVA_HOME pointing to JDK9. Maybe IJ is using JAVA_HOME somehow..

Comment: Didn't think of that I'll check it now

Comment: Nope it didn't affect anything

Comment: Try to run `echo %JAVA_HOME%` from the terminal of the IDE. Just to see if the IDE sees the change or not. In opposite case, restart the IJ.

Comment: The IDE apparently sees the change. It's pointing to JDK-9.0.4